# Properties of a metric induced by norm

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

I have been struggling with understanding the two properties that arise if we define a metric in terms of the norm $d(x,y) = ||x - y||$.

It is said that such a metric then has the following properties: $$d(x + z, y + z) = d(x,y)$$ **translation invariance**, and $$d(ax, ay) = |a| d(x,y)$$ **homogeneity**.

Now by the answers on this site I have seen that these properties are required to induce a norm from that metric (the converse) and that other metrics not induced by a norm might not have these two properties.

I am having problems seeing how these properties appear when a metric is defined in terms of the norm. I suppose that the homogeneity property appears like this: $$d(ax,ay) = \lVert a x-a y\rVert=\bigl\lVert a(x-y)\big\rVert=\lvert a\rvert\lVert x-y\rVert = |a|d(x,y).$$ Correct me if I am wrong, but this one is directly related to the homogeneity property of the norm so it makes sense. But how does this translation invariance appear?

Comment: $\|(x+z)-(y+z)\|=\cdots$

Comment: Did you mean $=\color{red}{|a|}d(x,y)$ in the last equation?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Yes, typo.

Comment: In fact on a linear space with a metric inducing the topology, we can always find a translation invariant metric. But the homogeneity is really typical for norms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
d(x+z, y+z) & = \| (x + z) - (y + z) \| \\
& = \| x - y \| \\
& = d(x, y)
\end{align*}

Comment: What I was most concerned about is which property of the norm proves translation invariance, but in fact only homogeinity utilises a norm property for the proof while translation invariance just algebraically manipulates it to prove. Am I right?

Comment: @MichaelMunta Yes. It’s a property based in the algebraic structure of the normed space, specifically its addition operation.

Comment: @MichaelMunta it’s mostly because we take a function (norm) of the difference of vectors.

Comment: I'm wondering as well, why is it called **translation** invariance?

Comment: @MichaelMunta Because geometrically that “$+z$” is a translation by (the vector) $z$.